# Exim - send certain "local" user mail to smtp

Tags: exim

I'm using Exim 3 and would like to know how to send some local addresses to the smtp server instead of Exim handling them as a localuser.  They are local addresses in the sense that they have the same domain as listed in 'local_domains' in exim.conf.

I tried using the "require_files" option on the localuser director in exim.conf, but with no luck.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exim3 has a strong separation between locally handled mail (Directors) and remote-handled mails (Routers) and it's rather hard to do what you want.

Exim3 is unsupported by upstream and *very* ancient and hard to configure to defend adequately against modern spam levels.

I **strongly** recommend switching to Exim4, where:

1. Implementing your desired result is trivial
2. The codebase is maintained
3. There are upgrade tools to help you migrate your config.